# Build fails due to different package location

Tags: realm

I'm new to realm db and tried to integrate it in our mobile app (Xamarin.Ios using Visual studio).

I've added the nuget to the PCL project as well as to the executable project
when building, the build fails with the following message:

```
1>C:\Projects\CoachApp-Fork\ExternalPackages\Realm.0.74.1\build\Realm.targets(6,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Projects\CoachApp-Fork\Build\Solutions\packages/Realm.0.74.1/tools/RealmWeaver.Fody.dll" because it was not found.
```

There seems to be a build task in realm that tries to copy the dll, however in our solution, the nuget packages are located at a different location (configured via Nuget.Config).

any ideas how to resolve this? i cannot simply change the nuget package location, as the build server relies on this...

Answer (score 0):

That was **my** clever trick you broke!

The problem is the location of the DLL for Fody is quite restrictive and yet the Xamarin templates have two different relative package directory locations depending on you having a multi-target project. (This was an *improvement* to cache packages per-solution, I think sometime in 2015.)

Can you put your own manual copy step into your build, at least for now, to put it there in advance? I realise this isn't an optimal solution but might work as a band-aid.

Comment: hey andy,
thank you for replying,
i guess i can give it a try and put the dll there myself. but won't the realm build script attempt to copy the dll anyway?

Comment: Ah now i think i understood. you suggested to drop the fody dll into the /solutiondir/packages... folder before the script runs, right?

i could do that also by putting the dll into source control (wont make the technical lead developer too happy :-) ). but do you think you'll be able to resolve this anytime soon?

Comment: @ccgre yes I'm suggesting put it where our step expects to copy from. It's a really ugly compromise just to get things going. Beyond that, we have to work out some configurability into the process which is awkward because we're about two steps removed - the Fody nuget installer is invoked as a dependency of ours and we can't run cleanup scripts in ours on OS X.

Comment: i've tried and failed to get it to work on the build server. i am not sure why, but i get errors when it tries to copy the realm weaver dll to /Tools.

Anyway, i will fall back to a sqlite solution for now because i lose to much time. but i'll be happy to go to realm when this issue is resolved.